# MutationObserver how to get a snapshot of DOM for specific mutation of stack array

Tags: javascript, dom, undo, mutation-observers

Having some problems with MutationObserver. While observing the document, which contains `contenteditable` elements, MO catches all the `document.execCommand`
invocations. Everything is good, but sometimes, dom endures some complicated mutations, so, observer-function receives a very big array of step-by-step mutations:

[image]

The problem is if I will choose, for example, one of the first mutations (like `mutation.type=="attributes"`) of the stack array, and it's `mutation.target` dom-element was *de facto* moved through the dom-tree to other parent OR it was actually removed from the DOM (move/remove event may be below at the same stack array), when I am trying to get, for example, `mutation.target.parent` or `mutation.target.previousSiblingElement` properties of the former chosen mutation (these properties are unlikely not passed inside the `MutationRecord` object), I am receiving the result of final document dom-tree (when the `mutation.target` is already moved/removed from the DOM), because all the `MutationRecord`'s in a mutations array are already happened, so, all the properties of `(HTMLElement)mutation.target` **excepting the latest**, are already likely may be not relevant, due to the probability that current mutations array contains events of the same `(HTMLElement)mutation.target` affection.

I am writing an undo/redo dispatcher, so, sometimes, I need to write down all the changes from the mutations stack array **with** an affecting element's parent to the memory by "forEaching" the `mutations` array, so, the problem which is described above makes things much times complicated to solve the problem!

Comment: You might explore using something like https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary

Comment: The only reliable way I can think of is using the deprecated DOM mutation events as those are synchronous.